# Grouping LongListSelector with ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: windows-phone, observablecollection, longlistselector

I have a ObservableCollection that I bind to a LongListSelector using the Silverlight toolkit in Windows Phone 7, how can I group the ObservableCollection so that I can use the jumplist control within the LongListSelector?

Regards,

Tim

Comment: I've successfully bound my ObservableCollection to the LongListSelector, but haven't made steps to implement the GroupHeader yet because I don't know where to start. Documentation is very hard to find on this subject.

Comment: If I put `LongListSelector` into Google, I find lots of tutorials?